Regex to match final word of first line of two-line subs
I'm trying to fine-tune a regex to quickly check if the auto-break feature of Subtitle Edit has produced any funny-looking breaks syntactic/semantic-segmentation-wise.
I have put together an extensive "do not break after" list over the years, so it mostly behaves, but it never hurts to double-check.
As it stands, I'm using this:
[a-z]+(?:\n[a-z]+)*$

As you can see in the screenshot, it gets the job done, even ignoring line breaks when any sort of punctuation is in the picture.

Still, how do I go about matching just the word charge in this example and ignoring the likes of call and look?
There are technically two line breaks between each caption group, so I suppose that's the one thing that can be leveraged to discriminate. Of course, I don't need either call or look to be flagged in this example because I manually go over that side of things while captioning, splitting lines at semantically logical places.
So, I basically only need to match the final word of the first line of two-line subs, provided there's no punctuation at the end of it, but, as I've said, what I'm currently using already takes care of that. I've looked far and wide here but haven't found a solution to this exact issue.
As for flavor, I use this sort of regexes to rapidly vet subs in a simple text editor, EditPad Pro to be exact. Copying/pasting off their website, "EditPad Pro’s regex flavor is highly compatible with the flavors used by Perl, Java, .NET and many other modern Perl-style regular expression flavors." I'm not exactly super tech-savvy when it comes to all things regex, but I've been able to compile quite a few to fit all of my post-subtitling needs by picking users' brains in different posts here and tweaking as needed, and this is the only one that keeps stumping me really because I have no clue how to filter out the second line of a two-line sub, which would save me a boatload of time while reviewing, especially when it comes to long files.
Any advice? Thanks in advance.

That is rather unclear, but try --> \d[\d:.]+\R.*\h\K[a-z]+(?=\R.)

Please mention regex flavor/environment.

To expand on the previous comment, please review the usage guidance on the Stack Overflow regex tag info page.

@bobblebubble Sorry about omitting flavor, guys. I've just edited the OG post.

@WiktorStribiżew Just gave that one a stab in EditPad, but no dice. Thanks anyway.

Try it in Notepad++. Look: https://regex101.com/r/HVNsfb/1

@Sarah Without knowing the exact task there are tons of ways to target the last word in the specific line if next line is not empty. 1.) Using capture groups and consuming: \b([a-z]+)$((?:\n\S.*)+) 2.) Capture and match only in the line after the "time-line"... ^(\d+:.*\n\S.*)\b([a-z]+)$(?=\n\S) 3.) Do the same using \K to reset: ^\d+:.*+\n\S.*\K\b[a-z]++$(?=\n\S) 4.) Using a variable length lookbehind... and many more ways.

If you know there can't be more than two line-subs, I'd simply use \b[a-z]+$(?=\n\S)

Thanks @bobblebubble EditPad won't even entertain these, no matches. Sorry for being totally out of depth with this. As I said, what I do is just open the srt file in this editor when I'm done captioning and use the regex feature. Over the years, I have put together, by trial and error, and saved up a bunch as favorites in this software to make sure everything is on the up and up. It's mostly stuff that the "Fix common errors" feature in SE won't actually fix, such as a name and surname ending up on different lines, for instance. Sorry again for not being able to make myself more clear.

@Sarah Would \b[a-z]++(?=\R\S) work? I wish you get it solved!  Haeding out now...

@WiktorStribiżew Oh, wow, I totally missed your follow-up comment earlier. Works like a charm indeed. Thanks. I do keep Notepad++ handy as well, but I use EditPad for this subtitling stuff because I have all these regexes neatly organized in there so I can quickly run through them. But it's no biggie firing up Notepad++ just for this one seeing as it saves me a boatload of time. Out of curiosity, any clue as to why EditPad falls short on this one? Regardless, thank you so much. This regex is a game-changer for me!

@bobblebubble Nope, EditPad doesn't seem to like \R. I get an "unknown regex token message". But it does work in Notepad++. I have noticed over the years that EditPad is a bit fussy when it comes to regexes, so no biggie switching to Notepad++ for this one. Thank you very much for your help. I actually have two now that do the trick :)

@Sarah Sounds good, Notepad++ is very nice anyway. If Editpad does not support \R I guess \b[a-z]+(?=\r?\n\S) could have worked (more efficient if using with $ end but I have some feeling \b[a-z]+$(?=\r?\n\S) wouldn't work either). Feel encouraged to post the solutions that worked for you as an answer, if you like.

EditPad’s regular expression engine matches \r and \n to a single CR and a single LF. If you want differences in line breaks to be handled automatically, use the full search panel and press Shift+Enter to type in an actual line break into your regular expression. - https://www.editpadpro.com/manual.html#optionregex

Thanks, guys, everything is crystal clear now.

Both of the following solutions work in Notepad++
\b[a-z]++(?=\R\S)

This regex matches one or more [a-z] possessively at \b a word-boundary if followed by a line-break and a non-whitespace. It works if there are not more than two lines below the time-line.
Regex101 demo

\d[\d:.]+\R.*\h\K[a-z]+(?=\R.)

Regex101 demo
The other pattern sticks to the time-line and matches in the next line up to a horizontal-space where the match gets reset by \K before matching one or more [a-z] if followed by a line-break and . any character. Obviously this would even work with more than 2 lines below the time-line.
